# How to connect Brain to computer?

Tags: science-based, computers, brain

I'm not talking about mind-uploading, but rather about connecting your consciousness to the computer to be able to live inside it.I'm talking rather about advanced bci, so you have all the experiences, senses you'd experience in real life but instead in video game/software.(in this computer)

Comment: Where? With which technology?

Comment: What does "connecting one's consciousness to the computer" mean? Do you have a physical definition of what consciousness is? That would be very much in advance of our current understanding of the brain (as a physical organ) and the mind.

Comment: It really depends on your definition of consciousness. It could be the electric signals from and to the brain, the actual soul of the user (however this is defined) or something else entirely.

Comment: "Living inside a computer" sounds an awful lot like mind-uploading to me. No upload means you'll remain living in your head.

Comment: So, for an objective observer, what would be the difference between `mind-uploading` and `connecting your consciousness to the computer to live inside it`?

Comment: This strongly reminds me of the technology used in the Anime *Sword Art Online*, though it may not be what you want depending on what the actual goal is.

Comment: I'm talking that you can disconnect from computer and go back info real world.Something like advanced BCI

Comment: The theory of mind is physicalism.

Comment: @michaelsmith so you're just talking about a brain computer interface, where you're _never_ "in" the computer at any time? Just experiencing a full-sensory virtual environment? Best update your question to clarify.

Comment: Sorry to see this was put on hold, but maybe I can suggest a few areas that will help you narrow down your topic to more specific questions.  Firstly, the computer needs to get a lot of information from the brain in order to be able to respond to it in any way that we could interpret consciously.  The amount of information going into the brain would perhaps need to be less.  So in terms of like an "internet connection" to the brain, the thing would need on the order of perhaps terabit download ( from the brain ) and perhaps gigabit upload ( to the brain ).

Comment: Second is the connection.  Ideally there would be a medusa of wires implanted throughout the brain - see [Neuralink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuralink).  Current technology is a couple of orders of magnitude shy of a good BCI connection, but that will eventually improve, 20 years out or so.  Other work has been done with [trans-cranial magnetic stimulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcranial_magnetic_stimulation), also promising as a non-invasive method, but also orders of magnitude shy.  The only option there is to use EEG type technology to receive brain activity.

Comment: Current [marketable technology](https://www.google.com/search?q=eeg+products) uses EEG, but it's only a one way connection, the computer receiving information and responding, but by some other action and not directly into the brain.  Used to control a quadcopter or move a mouse cursor or control a computer with the brain.

Comment: And finally any good connection ( one pulling a lot of useful data out of the brain ) requires pretty hefty machine learning software/hardware to interpret that data on the fly - i.e. to recognize what the person is thinking, wanting, commanding, etc.  The more data the more compute is needed to interpret it.  Today's tech aims at a price point for the consumer market, but nothing technically prevents going all in, streaming a very high-resolution "image" of the brain in real time and using a super computer to process the stream - assuming money is no object.

Comment: One last point, the up-stream, sending data back into the brain.  I suppose one could consider a full duplex connection ( having the same upload capacity as download ) and possibly even utilizing that upstream bandwidth. However, that would require lots of individual probes in many very small regions of the brain.  Physically inserted nodes are much more difficult to manage ( currently ) and I would bet on non-invasive magnetic stimulation ( it can be projected to localities in 3D space ) along with more advanced ML for managing that process.  Both are very hard problems.

Comment: I want to back-pedal the terabit download estimate a bit.  We don't need to know everything the brain does, i.e. how it processes information, though that would be an interesting thing to study.  But rather we only need to know what kind of information it's processing at any given time.  This can be accomplished by selectively analyzing only higher level information, signals that get passed around after one has recognized something as a "dog" or "cat" for example.  So perhaps a full duplex gigabit connection would suffice.  The brain has a magical way of "dreaming" the rest of the detail.

Answer (score 2):

**VR Headsets are a start, if you need to you can go deeper**

If you are talking of connection, our brain is in itself a massive computer, with sensory input affecting our thoughts and consciousness.

So to be inside a computer, you only need to 'hijack' the senses in order to be inside one.

The purpose of VR headsets is to give Sight and Sound senses to be convinced they are inside a computer environment. These are readily available. However the brain also receives other senses:

- Touch - these can be manipulated with computerised pressure suits
- Temperature - again, suits could accommodate this
- vibration - sound is a form of vibration
- electric fields - can easily be adapted
- Smell - a harder one, there are efforts to [digitise smells](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_does_it_take_to_reproduce_a_digitized_scent)
- Taste - similar to digitising smells

If you need more, you need to go deeper, and therefore you would need to hijack our nerve system directly, possibly at both the brain stem and eye stems. Getting electrical signals from these and diverting them to a computer, while providing altered electrical feedback form the computer, would allow us to 'be' inside the computer environment.

Be prepared for unpredictable results though, our nerve system has been slowly evolved over billions of years - you would need a pretty good computer to interpret so much complexity, and respond with proper responses.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer assumes you want to isolate the mind/consciousness of the user from their physical body while using the computer-brain interface*

I will borrow some technology from the Anime *Sword Art Online*, which should be quite close if not exactly what you are looking for. The following image shows a Nerve Gear, the first Full-Dive VR-Headset.

[image: A Nerve Gear]

It uses high-density microwave transceivers to transmit information to the users brain and blocks outgoing as well as incoming movement signals and other sensory information (such as the sense of touch), to ensure the safety of the user. While in the virtual world it is impossible to control your physical body, your mind and consciousness are completely separate from your actual body. Just start an application via a voice command or similar and you are completely in your virtual world, whatever that might be.